# Text Extraction from Image with Single letter in it

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have an image [image: F] not of much good quality with a single letter in it. I need to extract the value from this

I tried doing this with open CV. the code works on good quality image but need help to extract from this image

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import argparse
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread(r"/home/ubuntu/xyz/xyz.jpg")
img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=1.5, fy=1.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)
img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0)
img = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)\[1\]  
# Save the filtered image
cv2.imwrite(r"/home/ubuntu/xyz/rr.jpg", img)
# Read text with tesseract for python
result = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang="eng")
result
```

Answer (score 0):

why u need `Gaussian Blur` in this situation

```
img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0)
```

with a big window (5,5)

I think you can make a white border outside instead of resizing the image,
and you may use `erosion` technical to remove the noise from image

Comment: Thanks i will try. I am not good with working with images. Just started learning. is there a direct solution for now to solve this

Comment: if it s single text, you can build a simple classify image